# Key-value observing doesn't work for zoomScale

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm stuck with following problem. I have a UIScrollView, _myScrollView, and I want to have another UIScrollView following it's movements. So I'm using key-value observing for the properties "zoomScale" and "contentOffset", but the **observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:** method only report changes in "contentOffset", not in "zoomScale", though the zooming workes fine. (See code snippet below.) What could be the reason for this?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [_myScrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [_myScrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"zoomScale" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"zoomScale"]) {
        NSLog(@"zoomScale: %@", change); // Never gets called
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not everything is key-value observable. And changes can be made in a non-KVO compliant way. So this is no big surprise. Why are you using KVO for this anyway? You've got delegate methods up the wazoo.

Comment: Okay, maybe my attempt wasn't perfect - but do I really deserve to get downvoted!?

Comment: @turingtested: The downvote (and close vote) both seem unwarranted to me. This is a reasonable and clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zoomScale` property isn't KVO compliant. But `UIScrollViewDelegate` has a `scrollViewDidZoom` method that you can use to track changes to zoomScale.

Answer (score 1):

UIKit actually doesn't support KVO.

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html):

> Note: Although the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not
>   support KVO you can still implement it in the custom objects of your application, including custom views.

It does work sometimes (as you've seen), but support for it is undocumented and inconsistent. Use the delegate methods instead.

Comment: And KVO is relatively expensive, so it's not a good choice for binding values to UI elements in iOS.